# Please help me regarding relieving letter

Tags: work-experience, relieving-letter

I am a software engineer. I served in a company for 2.5 years but due to a lack of projects and work, I resigned. However, they forced me to stay.

I had an agreement with employer too. But just before 3 months, I resigned.
After a few days I had a good offer and was good for development point of view, so I didn't want to miss this.

I asked them to release me in one month as specified by the notice period,
but they didn't agree and asked me 200000 where the agreement was for 50000.

I told the same with the current organisation and they were ready without document. And i joined here.

Could this get me into trouble in the future?
If yes, then what should I do?

Comment: @user379013 I understand that English is not your first language and have cleaned your question up a little. However, it's still not clear to me. Can you [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/31455/edit) it and improve it further? Give the companies/employer/organisation fictional names X, Y, ... so that we know who you are talking about. Also: if with "good from ...view" you mean "the job looked good for my development career", then please say so. And: where does the relieving letter come in - you don't mention it anywhere in your text?

Comment: Note that this is not a place nor substitute for professional legal advice, and it sounds like that is what you may need if you intend to enforce an "agreement" or "notice period".

Comment: How could they force you to stay after you resigned?

Comment: This is a legal mess, you need a lawyer. You need to get this cleaned up for your own protection. I hope you have copies of the applicable contracts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would be any trouble in your current organization but it can pose trouble in two cases:

1. When you join some other organization in future, they may ask you to provide the relieving/ work-experience letter etc. from your first organization.
2. There is minor chance that it may affect your visa application, when time comes.

Second part of your question is that what you should do in such case.

(i) In case you have agreement with them in written, then you can challenge them legally. But I suppose you are from India and this can get cumbersome.

(ii) My suggestion would be that you negotiate with them. Get you experience letter from them for a lesser amount. Your first company will still be in win-win situation and hence, they might agree upon it.